# How to adjust the paper size in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

i have the following code to print the page, i want to add custom page size how do i do that?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = True
    PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = True
    PrintDialog1.Document = docToPrint
    Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()
    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        docToPrint.Print()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the paper size using DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize properties of document
Example:

```
Dim xCustomSize As New PaperSize("Legal", 850, 1400)

Me.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = xCustomSize
```

Fine more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: and how do i center the contents?

Comment: Do some research, or show us your code for center, If you face any error we can help you.

Comment: thanks i found the solution, i set my image properties and it worked!